# Can I force SoapClient to return arrays as arrays?

Tags: php, soap, asp.net-web-api, soap-client

I am fetching some data using SoapClient. I get this resuls from one of the calls:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [payTransIncome] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [payTransId] => 141281
                    [payTransItId] => 630260
                    [payTransBuyerId] => 1311

                )
        )
)
```

However the docs of this WebAPI say `payTransIncome` is an array.
Seems to me SoapClient found a one element array and converted it to a single stdClass object. And this makes it harder to parse because sometimes I think it might actually return more then 1 element.

Sure I can put everywhere checks `if (is_array())` but maybe there is a simple, more elegant way?

Comment: Try to set `features` to `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` in your SoapClient options.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Perfect, thank you! If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Answer added so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try to set `features` to `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` in your SoapClient options:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", ['features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of PHP, SoapClient may ignore the "features" option.
That was my case using PHP 5.3.
But you can always cast an object of stdClass to array:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
$objResult = $client->__soapCall("someFunction");
$objArray = (array)$objResult;
```